# Why I get gibberish when sending request from MAC to PC?

Tags: iphone, networking, network-protocols, endianness

I send some data from MAC to PC. From MAC I send it from iPhone emulator and in PC I catch the request in Visual Studio. If the data is ENGLISH letters, so I receive normal data, if data contains RUSSIAN, HEBREW and etc letters, so I receive gibberish.
Does it something with the endianness?

Comment: How are you sending? How are you receiving? If the data is supposed to be standard UTF-8, how are you making sure your client and server both send and receive UTF-8? Or are you using different character encodings? Can you post a small reproducer client and server?

Comment: When I send the request I can see in the fiddler that the **Content-Type** header is **UTF-8**, doesn't this enough?

Comment: No, it's not necessarily enough.  It's certainly enough for *you* to know that the content is encoded in UTF-8.  However, if you're viewing this in VS, in either a debugger or console output, you will not see the correct characters, because VS doesn't necessarily know what "Content-Type" means in the context of your application.  How are you trying to display and verify the text data coming across?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: It seems it would be unlikely for endianness to be a problem here after all.

It sounds like the data is encoded in UTF-8, and as such is actually coming across the wire just fine.  Visual Studio simply won't display utf-8 characters properly; however if you managed to copy the string data out and dump it into something that can decode utf-8, you'd probably find that your string data is still intact.

Comment: How old is the Mac? :) Chances are good if @theateist is doing iPhone development that he's on an Intel Core2 Duo or Core i[57] processor, same as the PC...

Comment: True that.  I still have a PPC lying around :)

Comment: @sarnold, you wanna to say that this is not endianness problem?

Comment: @theateist, this might be an endianness problem, but as chomp points out, UTF-8 is endian-neutral, and it is most common these days -- but only if both endpoints are prepared to use it. And _that_ is my best guess; you're using UTF-8 on client but [windows code pages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page) or something else on the PC. Need more data. :) Post client and server code that shows the problem, or at least what was sent vs what was received.